# JavaScript Object Decorator

Tags: javascript, proxy, clone, decorator, overriding

I have a JavaScript object that has multiple methods:

```
var actualObject = {

    foo: function(){},
    bar: function(){},
    …

}
```

However, the actual object that I want people to use is `proxy`. It should forward all its calls to `actualObject`. The simplest way of doing that would be simply assigning `actualObject` to `proxy`.

```
proxy = actualObject;
```

However, for some methods, I want proxy to have additional functionality.

```
proxy.bar = function(arguments) {
    console.log('do something beforehand');
    actualObject.bar(arguments);
    console.log('do something afterward');
}
```

The problem is, if `proxy` and `actualObject` are the same, this overridden bar method will cause a recursion. Thus my question: What is the most "idiomatic" way of cloning a JavaScript object but overriding certain methods in a way that would allow calling the original methods from within the overriding ones?

Comment: You can have the `actualObject` as the prototype for your `proxy`. Then, `proxy` can override any properties of it's prototype by defining them on `proxy`.

Comment: Works perfectly! You should post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the `proxy` prototype to be `actualObject` then define the function in `proxy`:

```
var proxy = Object.create(actualObject);

proxy.bar = function(arguments) {
    console.log('do something beforehand');
    actualObject.bar(arguments);
    console.log('do something afterward');
}
```